# Setting value using filtered data

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I'm trying to open a sheet (Archive) from my inventory sheet, filter the data in the second sheet and then copy the filtered data to a sheet on the inventory. Everything is working except that the filtered data only copies  the data from rows in the first contiguous range. My code is as follows

```
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim nOoFrOWS As Long
Dim oSht As Worksheet






Workbooks.Open ("C:\Inventory\Archive.xlsm") '<- at opening a workbook it becomes the active one
Set oSht = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Archive") '<-- set the destination worksheet in the activeworkbook

With ActiveSheet
.ListObjects("Archive").Range.AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:=mOrder
nOoFrOWS = .AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count - 1                              '# of rows in Inventory
End With
Unload Me

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("RAM").Range("A2:K" & nOoFrOWS).Value = oSht.Range("Archive[[QTY]:[RTK]]").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Value


oSht.Parent.Close False
```

What am I doing wrong?

edit: I don't know if it is pertinent, but the range in the archive (from which I am copying) is not the entire table. I have more rows, but These are all I need for this application.

Also, is there a way to do this without the clipboard by using .value or am I stuck with using the copy paste method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your working with a table you can copy the visible cells in the `databodyrange`.

No need to activate or select anything - just work with the referenced files & sheets.

```
Sub Test()

    Dim wrkBk As Workbook
    Dim mOrder As Long

    mOrder = 5

    'You can reference the workbook without it being active.
    Set wrkBk = Workbooks.Open("C:\Inventory\Archive.xlsm")

    With wrkBk.Worksheets("Archive").ListObjects("Archive")
        .Range.AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:=mOrder
        'Copy the DataBodyRange (Range would include the headers).
        .DataBodyRange.Resize(, 11).SpecialCells(xlVisible).Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("RAM").Range("A2")
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. I've not heard about databodyrange before. I'll try it now. Does this code work without the clipboard as .value does?

Comment: I just tried it and when it gets to With wrkBk.Worksheets("Archive").ListObjects("Archive") it gives an error '9' "Subscript out of range"

Comment: I just looked through the locals for the worksheet `listobject` and found `databodyrange` sitting in there.  Contained the same info that a normal range would, so I tried it.  It does use the clipboard though (uses `Copy`).

Comment: You do have your data in a worksheet called 'Archive' and in a table also called 'Archive'?

Comment: Yes. the table "archive" is in a sheet called "Archive" which is in a file called "Archive"  I wanted to make sure that it was known to be an archive.

Comment: Just noticed - if you're using the exact code above I'm referencing `wrkBk` to `ThisWorkbook` (I've removed that line now).  Wrkbk should be set to `Workbooks.open.....`

Comment: I did that, but now it filters out all the data and doesn't leave what I have set to mOrder (which is in a userform). Maybe I should have mentioned that this is being run from a userform.

Comment: What value does `mOrder` hold?  Is it a number, text or a reference to the control on the form?  I've just set it as `long`, but that was a guess.

Comment: It's a reference to a combobox in a userform. I didn't notice that it was set as long. I got rid of that and it is now referencing the userform. So, copies all of the data, but it's copying too much. All I want is A:K, but it is filling in the entire table width which is A:R.

Comment: Have added code to resize it to A:K (first 11 columns).